# accordion style problems

Tags: jquery, accordion, styles

Thank you for your responce regarding the below answer:

"When I need to override the styles applied by jQuery UI elements, I usually add a stylesheet that I load after the jQuery UI stylesheet and put my overrides into it, using the same selectors so that I know that my styles will take precedence. In this case look for the styles associated with the accordion or the widget state and override them."

Could you please advise how to add a stylesheet after the jQuery UI stylesheet has loaded???

Thank you very much!!!!!

Ash

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's not silly way (rather ugly hack) but adding to your styles !important should fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can add the !important keyword to your styles.

```
.overrideStyle {
  color: #ccc !important;
}
```